# Controls overlay for video on iPhone/iPad

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, video, html5-video

I am writing a webapp where I need to display a video and some (non standard) controls for it, which should appear in overlay. So create some divs and position them over the video, with a higher z-index.

Still, on iPhone and iPad, it appears those controls are not clickable. I register actions for the click event, but that is not fired at all when I tap on the controls. I understand I can have no control while the video is actually playing (it even goes fullscreen), but the problem is that the controls are unusable even when the video is stopped.

I have also tried to remove the `controls` attribute from the video, with no effect.

> Is there a way to register click events for elements that are positioned over a video on iPhone/iPad?

Comment: Try adding `style="pointer-events:none;"` to the video element. This should make the video unclickable, and thus your buttons clickable. Not sure if it works though

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and got it working by setting the CSS property of the HTML5 video element while

**paused** to `-webkit-transform:scale(0.01);`

**playing** to `-webkit-transform:scale(1);`

The problem is that the HTML5 video element on iOS seems to hijack the click events in the areas (of the elements layered on top) that are contained in the bounding box of the video element. If the bounding box is made smaller with scale(0.01) or the bounding box is pushed off the screen with translateX(-2560px), no element areas are directly above the video element and the click events will get fired.

Comment: can you add an example please?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is to make the element with controls obstruct the whole video, not just a section of it - this will help you debug it in any case.  Another approach is to use touch events instead of click events.  These execute faster and are usually not over-ridden.
Sample code would be helpful.