# Links overlaid on top of HTML5 mobile video stop working after user clicks 'done' in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, youtube-api, html5-video

My application contains full screen Youtube videos, with information and links overlaid on top of it. I'm using the jQuery plugin [TubePlayer](http://tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin) to embed the Youtube videos in a `<div>` element. The links and content are overlaid in other `<div>`s, with higher Z-indexes.

This works great on desktop browsers.

It also works fine in iOS when the user first visits a page. The links are overlaid on top of the video, and the Youtube "play" button appears on top of a poster image of the video (see image). All the links are clickable. When a user presses "play" the video opens in Safari's full-screen video player.

[image: All overlaid links work correctly when page first loads.]

The problem occurs when a user presses "done" to exit the iOS video player. The player returns to the previous screen. All the links are still visible above the image, but now they are no longer clickable. Additionally, the red Youtube play button has been replaced by the gray iOS play button (see image).

[image: After users pressess "done", the overlaid links are still viewable but no longer clickable.]

I'm stumped about why I can see the overlaid links, but not click them. Any ideas on how I could handle this? I'm open to almost any type of solution.

Comment: It looks like the problem comes down to the video item taking over the screen. Here is a different SO question that might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325311/controls-overlay-for-video-on-iphone-ipad

Comment: I opted to change the UI so the most important elements appear underneath the video. Not ideal but works OK.